# Running kate as root

Tags: root, kate

I'm using Kubuntu 18.04 and I want to run the **kate** editor with root privileges  `sudo kate` produces the message `running kate as root is not possible`. I think that's utterly silly.  How can I bypass it?

Answer: just edit the file, even if it's a system file, using plain old**kate**.  You don't need root privileges to edit it; you only need root privileges to save it.  When you save a system file, you'll be asked for the root password.  Supply it and the save takes place.  Easy!!

Comment: You can't without modifying the program and recompiling it afaik.  You don't ***need*** to run kate as root anyway.  As long as you have read privileges on the text file you can open it and if you make any changes when you try to save it will bring up a dialog box that will ask you for your password and will save the file successfully and "root" privileges will stay for the normal timeout you have on your system. (I think default is 5 minutes)

Comment: The GUI is owned by the user, and a secure environment shouldn't allow another user (root) to have access to a user's GUI.   Your *silly* is security best practices, and whilst X may allow it (back from the early 80s where windows were from other machines due to slower cpus then in use), other more security-conscious enviornments (Wayland etc) will not.

Comment: This explains why they disabled the ability to run `kate` as root. https://cgit.kde.org/kate.git/commit/?id=9adcebd3c2e476c8a32e9b455cc99f46b0e12a7e

Comment: There are many non-nanny editors that are every bit as good and even better than Kate.

Comment: Because of Bill Gates "We'll tell you what you can or can't do" mentality (I am beginning to think Linux is being taken over by ex MS programmers) I have just switched from Kate to GEDIT - too bad, I preferred Kate. I am re-thinking the whole KDE paradigm. I am a  ex-sys admin living at home alone and they are trying to tell me how to use my computer - I don't think so!

Comment: Post your edit containing the "answer" as an actual **answer**.

Comment: Additional problem: What if you want Kate to act as a drop-in replacement for abominations like vim/emacs (I’m an old vim/emacs user, and I’ve been cured, thanks) in $EDITOR, You need to launch Kate from root, but not be root, but use the current user’s GUI instead, and if it’s not availabe, use e.g. `tilde`.

Answer (score 11):

I think I may have a newer version of `kate` installed. I'm running 18.04 and I get the following message:

```
Executing Kate as root is not possible. To edit files as root use:
SUDO_EDITOR=kate sudoedit <file>
```

so it seems you can edit files as root by using the following command:

```
SUDO_EDITOR=kate sudoedit <file>
```

However, you won't be able to edit files as root in any directory that is not owned by root. Because of this, you *must* also specify a filename when you run `kate` using `sudoedit`.

---

You can easily set an alias for `sudokate` by adding the following line to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
alias sudokate='SUDO_EDITOR=kate sudoedit'
```

Then, run the following command to source your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Also, don't forget to source your `~/.bashrc` file in all other open terminals to apply the changes.

Now, you can run the `sudokate` command to edit files in directories owned by root.

---

[SOURCE](https://cgit.kde.org/kate.git/commit/?id=9adcebd3c2e476c8a32e9b455cc99f46b0e12a7e)

Answer (score 10):

You can edit system files with Kate 19.04.3 (available in Kubuntu 19.10) or in Kubuntu 19.04 (with [kubuntu-backports ppa](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports?field.series_filter=disco)) installed.

Simply open the file you wish to edit in Kate, edit it, and click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. A PolicyKit window will appear prompting you for your password. Provide it and click *Okay*.

[image: editing system files in Kate]

Comment: This is a nice solution to the problem, and is adaptable (I think) to most environments.  It works by avoiding the false paths of trying to run kate somehow with root privileges.  The essential idea is marvelously simple: just edit your system file with vanilla kate, try to save it, and supply the root password when you're asked for it.

Comment: So what if you're actually logged in as root?

Comment: @Joshua You shouldn't be. Follow good security practices and you won't run into this issue.

Comment: @gronostaj: Logging in as root on the console is a lot more secure than elevating a process in an X session. Even polkit can be hijacked.

Comment: @Joshua Sorry, I don't follow. Why is logging in as root (to perform some task) more secure than running selective processes as root? And what does X have to do with it? What do you mean by "even polkit can be hijacked"?

Comment: @gronostaj: A libc trojan can hijack `exec()` to do something else, like give you a fake login prompt and pass the real password to its own invocation of `sudo`. But a libc trojan can't hijack through Ctrl-Alt-Fn followed by root login and `startx`.

Comment: @Joshua Can a libc trojan be installed without root in the first place?

Comment: @gronostaj: Yes. All it needs is to write to .Xsession and set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or `LD_PRELOAD`.

Comment: What can you do when the policykit does not open this prompt? How do you enable it?